React Native app stuck on splash screen only on Galaxy S24 with Android 14 after clearing storage
Issue:
I'm experiencing a strange issue with my React Native app that only occurs on the Samsung Galaxy S24 running Android 14. The app gets stuck on the splash screen only on the first launch or after the app’s storage is cleared via settings. This issue doesn't happen when the app's storage is intact (even if the cache is cleared), nor does it happen on other devices (including older Samsung models and other Android 14 devices) or emulators.
Steps to reproduce:
Install the app on a Galaxy S24 (Android 14).
Clear the app storage (via the app settings).
Launch the app.
The splash screen either loops and gets stuck indefinitely.
However:
If I launch the app, then close it and reopen it without clearing storage, the app works perfectly fine.
I’ve tested this on multiple devices (other Samsung models, non-Samsung devices) and emulators , and I cannot replicate the issue on any device except the Galaxy S24.
What I've tried so far:
Checked async operations in the splash screen: I’m fetching user location and initializing app settings (such as loading tokens and checking storage) in the splash screen. I’ve ensured all these have fallback values in case data is missing or permissions are denied.
Added extensive error logging: No errors are being thrown during the splash screen process. All the async operations (location fetching, token checking, navigation readiness) seem to complete successfully.
Permissions and Geolocation: Ensured that location permissions are requested properly and handled gracefully if denied.
Cache and storage management: The issue persists only when all app storage is cleared, not when just the cache is cleared.
Environment:
React Native version: 0.73.6
Samsung Galaxy S24
Android 14
Devices tested: Galaxy S24 (issue persists), Galaxy S21 (works fine), Pixel (works fine), multiple emulators (works fine)
Question:
Why is this issue only occurring on the Galaxy S24 with Android 14, and only when the storage is cleared?
Could this be related to some specific handling of storage or permissions on Galaxy S24?
Any suggestions on debugging this further or resolving the issue?

You may be trying to do something without permission, when you clear the storage, you also remove permissions. Try checking the native log, it is probably if you are doing something without permission. https://blog.logrocket.com/diagnosing-react-native-crashes/
